# How do I filter large set of points (481,308) in QGIS attribute table by fixing the extents(Lat Long values)

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter, expression, qgis-python-console

I have a large set of points (481,308) in single QGIS layer with the attribute table(ID, LAT, LONG,..ETC). But I only need points which fall inside particular area or polygon, I have fixed the extents of the polygon, as shown below:

1)North of Point1 12.978649°   77 .603701°

2)East of point1     12.952451°    77.633003°

3)East of point2     12.930359°    77.647210°

4)South of point2   12.893661°   77.636665°

5)West of point2    12.906764°   77.597081°

6)West of point1   12.952262°    77.577471°

What expression should I use to filter out points which come inside my polygon area?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming coordinates are Lat/Long, an example layer from **Random points in extent**:

[image]

[image]

Use **Select by expression** with `intersects()` function between point's geometry and desired polygon:

```
intersects( $geometry, geom_from_wkt( 'POLYGON((77.603701 12.978649, 77.633003 12.952451, 77.647210 12.930359, 77.636665 12.893661, 77.597081 12.90676, 77.577471 12.952262, 77.603701 12.978649))' ))
```

*Don't forget to close the polygon*

The result:

[image]

---

## Step by step procedure for this reproducible example:

[image]

Comment: And add spatial index to your point layer to seed up selection.

Comment: @Zoltan yes,  thanks for your contribution. With *Processing Toolbox / QGIS geoalgorithms / Vector general tools / Create spatial index*

Comment: Thank you@aldo_tapia for your time. I used this expression as u mentioned  intersects( $geometry, geom_from_wkt( 'POLYGON((77.603701 12.978649, 77.633003 12.952451, 77.647210 12.930359, 77.636665 12.893661, 77.597081 12.90676, 77.577471 12.952262, 77.603701 12.978649))' )), am getting output error, unexpected '(', expecting COMMA or ')'

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18, I didn't find Create spatial index under Vector general tools

Comment: @AmarCr Do you have `,` as decimal separator in your computer?

Comment: @aldo_tapia As per my knowledge its comma only. Where do I check what " , " stands for on my computer as default?  Sorry if am being silly, bear with me being new to this.

Comment: Depends of your Operating System. But usually is located in regional / language settings

Comment: Excuse me but ... what kind of "spatial index" is created using this **"create spatial index"** treatment ? is it a .qix file ? is it then really taken in account by the **"select by expression"** formula ?

Comment: @snaileater "*Spatial indexes are methods to speed up queries of geometries*" from [QGIS:Becoming a GIS Power User](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788299725). So, it's taken in account when a "select by expression" query is made

Comment: @AmarCr I edited my answer adding a gif procedure. Check if you are making the same for this example. If works, should do it for your dataset

Comment: @aldo_tapia i know what is the definition and general purpose of a spatial index but in that case ... in term of files and/or file format ... which file(s) is generated and how can one be sure it is taken in account by the "select by expression" ? is the dataset of this question based on .shp file format ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a polygon with your extent (I dont really understand how you define the polygon extent, the number of point is unclear...) then use the select by location fonction (in the vector menu or in the processing toolbox) to select your point.

[image]

Depending if you need to reuse the selection polygon you could create it in a temporary layer or in a more durable format.

You could also use the select by expression button with this expression (replace the X and Y by the vertices coordinate of your extent polygon)

```
within(  $geometry ,geom_from_wkt( 'POLYGON ((X1 Y1, X2 Y2, ... ...,Xn Yn ))'))
```

EDIT:
 if you want to filter your data you could try to adapt the previous expression to SQL in the query builder (I tried, but can't get it to work...)